# Exporting Excel cell data to database via Excel macro?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

Can I create a macro written in C# for Excel that allows me to export a cell's data to a SQL Server or Access database?

Basically, I'd like to create a button in Excel that saves the data in certain cells to a database. Can this be done?

Instead of creating a UI from scratch for a program, I've decided using Excel as the user environment would be better for business needs.

Comment: Does it have to be written in C#? Aren't macros in Excel typically written in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to automate Excel by using Visual C# to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302096) would be a good starting point.

Be aware, you're going to find it frustrating to control what people attempt to enter into the Excel sheet, as the inherit flexibility of the data works again your efforts to write it to a database destination.